# IIS Web.config re-direct one subfolder to another

Tags: asp.net, web, iis, web-config

I have the below routing rule in my web.config file but it does not work for a route like:

[www.domain.com/folder/new-sub/page](http://www.domain.com/folder/new-sub/page)

to

[www.domain.com/folder-new/new-sub/page](http://www.domain.com/folder-new/new-sub/page)

as I intended. Could anyone help me correct the below rule so that it will work for the above use case?

```
<rule name="Redirecting folder to folder-new" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^folder/$" />
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/folder-new" />
            </rule>
```

Edit - to be more specific...i dont want to hard code new-sub/page ... i want anything that is in the "folder" subdirectory to the "new-folder" subdirectory

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i fixed it:

```
<rule name="Redirecting folder to new-folder" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^/?folder/(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/new-folder/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test8" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^folder/new-sub/page$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="folder-new/new-sub/page" />
</rule>
```

Comment: sorry for not being more specific...i dont want to hard code new-sub/page ... i want anything that is in the "folder" subdirectory to the "new-folder" subdirectory